# PHP build json from a dynamic number of arrays

Tags: php

I have a dynamic number of pages in my web project. It depends on data from the database. I may have 1 page or 10 pages. I put the data selected on each page in session, and finally want to build an array. At the moment I am building JSON from 4 arrays. (In session all the keys are level + int in ascending order. If session x is missing I don't have any data on 6+ levels)

```
$level1 = array();
$level2 = array();
$level3 = array();
$level4 = array();

if (isset($_SESSION['level1'])) {
    $level1 = $_SESSION['level1'];
}
//the same for 3 more levels in session


$array = array(
    "first"  => ($level1),
    "second" => ($level2),
    "third"  => ($level3),
    "fourth" => ($level4)
);

json_encode($array);
```

Example of output of the json_encode($array):

```
{"first":["1","2"],"second":["4","6","8","9"],"third":["13","14","17","18"],"fourth":["33","34","35","36"]}
```

I tried to check how would json_encode work with array_push(), but I get an array of JSON objects instead of a single json object.

```
$result = array();
array_push($result, ["key1" => $_SESSION["level1"]]);
array_push($result, ["key2" => $_SESSION["level2"]]);
array_push($result, ["key3" => $_SESSION["level3"]]);

echo json_encode($result);
```

and the output:

```
[{"key1":["1","2"]},{"key2":["4","5","6"]},{"key3":["13","14","15"]}]
```

I will make everything iteratively, but I want to know if it is possible to make a single JSON object instead of array of JSONs. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add the keys to the array without any need for a function.

```
$result = array();
$result["key1"] = $_SESSION["level1"];
$result["key2"] = $_SESSION["level2"];
$result["key3"] = $_SESSION["level3"];

echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: Thank you! This solved my question! In some minutes I will be able to accept your answer